# Any link between IQ and a person's ability to create or mimic sounds?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, intelligence, hearing, evolutionary-psychology, auditory-discrimination

Reading some articles about animals and speech, and it just brushes a bit of the neurology of it, but that got me curious:

Is there any link between a person's (or an animal's) mimicry skill and/or their ability to create complex noises just by manipulating their body to their overall intelligence?

**Note**, I'm not referring to "speech", ie. the actual comprehension and assignment of value to those noises; I'm just curious if the *ability* and/or the creativity of making and/or mimicking those noises has any correlation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Howard Gardner and his theory of Multiple Intelligence, I can propose that there is no link between IQ and the ability to mimic sound.

The IQ test (originating in the work by Alfred Binet) is not a measure of intelligence pre-se, but rather a measure of the ability of the subject to comprehend in the manner expected.  [Look for Gardner's explanation of the Hammer, Screw Driver and Nail question.]  Gardner proposes that we have the ability to either master or lack in 7 different types of intelligence.  (Not as in one stronger than the other, more like at different levels for each one.)

IQ measures some elements of linguistic, mathematical and spacial intelligence, but does not measure the others.  According to Gardner, the musical intelligence is the ability to comprehend tones, and patterns in sound quicker than others.  I thus propose that mimicking should have some direct correlation with Musical Intelligence, and since Musical Intelligence in not a measure in the IQ test there will be no link.

Comment: Note that Gardner himself has since [retracted his stance](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781316422250.037) on multiple intelligences.